# JavaScript - How to pass a variable from one async function to another?

Tags: async-await

I have spent a good few hours on trying to figure this out but drawing a blank.

I need to pass an array from one async function to another. Problem is, I am very new to this whole async/await world.

My code is below. I need to pass **elems** to the **step2** function

```
var selenium = require('selenium-webdriver');
var Builder = selenium.Builder;
var By = selenium.By;
var Key = selenium.Key;
var util = selenium.util;
var firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
var http = require('http');
var querystring = require('querystring');

async function startBot() {
  var driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').build();

  await driver.get('randomSite');

  if(true){//Putting this here as it may have to do with scope. I am not sure

    async function step1(){
      for(var p=0; p <5 ; p++){//elems is undefined
        var elem1 = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]")).getText();
        var elem2 = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]")).getText();

        var elems = [elem1, elem2]; //How do I pass this array to tge step2 funtion?
      }
    }

    if(true){//Putting this here as it may have to do with scope. I am not sure

      var char1 = 1;
      var char2 = 2;

      //button1
      async function step2(){
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
          if(elems[i] == char1){//elems is undefined
            await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[" + i + "]")).click().then(function(res, err){
              if(err){ reject(err); };
            });
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      await step1();
      await step2();

    }
  } 
};

startBot();
```

Comment: It is generally cleaner to _return the value from one function and pass it to the next_, when applicable. Otherwise, _modifying external state works exactly the same as with non-async functions_ (in terms of scope etc.), _except_ that one needs to be a little more aware when ensuring execution relationships; in this case that is trivially done with the “await” before each call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the elems array as a parameter to the step2 function. However, you have to do some modifications:

```
async function step1(){
  for(var p=0; p <5 ; p++){
    var elem1 = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]")).getText();
    var elem2 = await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]")).getText();

    var elems = [elem1, elem2];
  }
  return step2(elems);
}

async function step2(elems){
  for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if(elems[i] == char1){
      await driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div/div[" + i + "]")).click().then(function(res, err){
        if(err){ reject(err); };
      });
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

And only use await with the step1 function:

```
 await step1();
```

That's because we returned another promise `step2(elems)` from the step1 function. Therefore, the await keyword will have to wait for both step1 and step2. Remember that when you call an asynchronous function you always get a promise.

Answer (score 0):

Define `elems` outside the function.

Comment: I need it in the function though